# Сравнить индексы массивов

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
$arr  = ['a','b','c','d'] 
$arr2 = ['b','c','d']
```

Я могу как-то сделать, чтобы повторяющиеся элементы получили во втором массиве индексы первого? То есть, чтобы это выглядело `[1] => b [2] => c [3] => d у $arr2`.

Comment: Зачем? Конкретно в этом примере ты можешь добавить в начало второго массива еще 1 элемент

Comment: В реальном примере элементов больше, там не получится просто добавить в другие массивы.

Comment: Какую задачу ты таким образом пытаешься решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё один вариант:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
$arr2 = ['b','c','d'];

$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr2 as $item){
    if(in_array($item, $arr)){
        $key = array_search($item, $arr);
        $arr3[$key] = $item;
    }
}
```

Другой случай, если во втором массиве будут элементы которых нет в 1м

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
$arr2 = ['b','c','d','j'];

$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr2 as $item){
    if(in_array($item, $arr)){
        $key = array_search($item, $arr);
        $arr3[$key] = $item;
    }else{
        $arr3[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если элементы будут повторяться?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr  = ['a','b','c','e','d'];
$arr2 = ['b','c','d'] ;

$arr2 = array_intersect($arr, $arr2);
print_r($arr2);
```

или

```
$diff = array_diff($arr, $arr2);
$arr2 = $arr;

foreach ($diff as $key => $val){
    unset($arr2[$key]);
}

print_r($arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = ['a','b','c','d'] ;
    $arr2 = ['b','c','d']  ;
    $result = array_intersect($arr, $arr2);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {    
        foreach ($result as $key1 => $value1) {
            if( $value == $value1 ) {
                $arr3[$key] = $value1;
            }
        }
    }    
    print_r($arr3);    
?>
```

Comment: а если у второго массива будет элемент которого нет в первом? Тогда он не запишется в новый массив

Comment: $arr2[$key]=в таком случаи будут повторы